# How can I search for multiple values using multidimensional Array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array, excel-2007

This code is now working to search multiple values in multiple sheets.
How can I fix it to support searching multiple values at the same time without having to write every one . For example, I want to put in column A all my search values, and then I click on search, and it should search and give the value for all of them at the same time. What should I change in the code to do this function?
Please see the code and the images.

```
 Dim i, j, k, l, m, n, no_sheets As Variant
 Dim key, cursor, sheetname As Variant
 Dim flag As Variant
 Dim sheet1_count, sheet1_row, row_count As Integer
 Dim Arr() As Variant

     sheet1_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A:A"))

     no_sheets = 3 ' Number of sheets
     k = 2
     sheet1_row = sheet1_count 'My start in result sheet

     key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & sheet1_count) ' The value that the user will put in searching sheet in column A

     For i = 2 To no_sheets ' sheet2 then sheet3 then sheet4 then sheet5 ..etc
         flag = False
         sheetname = "Sheet" & i
         row_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A:A")) ' It's a counter that will contain the range of row A in each sheet
     For j = 1 To row_count 'I'll start from row 1 until the last sheet
         cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A" & j) 'Searching in column A in each sheet (1st row - last row) and put the value in this variable
             If key = cursor Then ' If the entering value in sheet1 equal the value that we have in current sheet, do the following
             ' Copying the data

             flag = True ' The data found

                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("B" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("C" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("D" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("E" & j)
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F" & sheet1_row) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("F" & j)

                 sheet1_row = sheet1_row + 1
                Else

         End If
     Next j 'Go to the next row
Next i 'Go to the next sheet
    MsgBox "finished, Do another search..!"


            If key <> cursor Then
              flag = False  ' If the value not found

                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"
                  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & sheet1_row) = "Not found"



            End If



       End Sub

   Sub MatchUnMatch_Click()
Dim i, j, k, l, m, n As Integer
Dim ListA_count, ListB_count, ListC_count, ListD_count, ListE_count As Integer
Dim key, cursor As String
Dim flag As Boolean

ListA_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnmatch").Range("A:A"))
ListB_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnmatch").Range("B:B"))
'ListA_count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
'MsgBox ListA_count & " " & ListB_count
'=======================================================================================================
'
'
' Matching Logic for List 'A' and List 'B'
'
'
'=======================================================================================================
k = 2
For i = 2 To ListA_count
    key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("A" & i)

    For j = 1 To ListB_count
        cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("B" & j)
        'MsgBox "Key=" & Key & " Cursor=" & cursor
        If key = cursor Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("C" & k) = key
            k = k + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'=======================================================================================================
'
'
' List 'A' items not in List 'B'
'
'
'=======================================================================================================
ListC_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnmatch").Range("C:C"))

k = 2
For i = 2 To ListA_count
    key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("A" & i)
    flag = False
    For j = 1 To ListC_count
        cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("C" & j)
        If key = cursor Then
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If flag = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("D" & k) = key
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i

'=======================================================================================================
'
'
' List 'B' items not in List 'A'
'
'
'=======================================================================================================
k = 2

For i = 2 To ListB_count
    key = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("B" & i)
    flag = False
    For j = 1 To ListC_count
        cursor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("C" & j)
        If key = cursor Then
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If flag = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MatchUnMatch").Range("E" & k) = key
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
End sub
```

[see the image please, to understand what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dxvu.png)I want to put in row A in search sheet (first sheet) many numbers and then I want to click on search button one time only that should give me all the values at the same time.I don't want to click one search more than one time.
I want someone to fix it for me please. As soon as possible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*) updated after OP's requested functionality to save data from previous runs and have numbers not found in "data" sheets marked as "NOT FOUND"

(**) updated after OP's request to handle a variable number of columns

(***) updated to fix FindItems() function to handle non contiguous cells range

(****) updated to fix `iRow` updating in sub Main()

(*****) updated to have items to be searched in sheets whose cell "A1" has same content as that of "base" sheets

(******) updated to have items to be searched in column A of all data sheets, whatever the header of that column

While I was doing my code, Cornel's already given you an answer which is ok

however should you ever want to manage:

- any different number of "data" Sheets (i.e.: sheets to seek for item number in its column "A" and gather relevant data from adjacent columns)
- multiple occurrences of a "number" in any "data" sheet
- (*) functionality to save previous data already in "base" sheet resulting from previous runs
- (*) functionality to mark "NOT FOUND" in "base" sheet when number not found on any "data" sheet
- (**) functionality to handle a variable number of columns

then you may want to use the following code

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim items() As Variant, itemToFind As Variant
Dim itemsNumber As Long, previousDataNumber As Long, dataShtNumber As Long, iRow As Long, i As Long, j As Integer
Dim itemsSht As Worksheet, dataShts() As Worksheet
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim itemFound As Boolean
Dim columnsNumberToCopyAndPaste As Long

columnsNumberToCopyAndPaste = 7 '<== here you set the number of columns to be copied form "data" sheet and pasted in "base" sheet

Set itemsSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' this is the "base" sheet you take "numbers" from its column A, starting at row 2

Call GetItems(itemsSht, items(), itemsNumber, previousDataNumber) ' gather all "numbers" to be searched for in "data" sheets

Call GetDataWorksheets(dataShts(), ThisWorkbook, "Sheet1", dataShtNumber) ' gather all "data" sheets

iRow = 1
For i = 1 To itemsNumber 'loop through "numbers"

    itemToFind = items(i) ' "number" to be searched for in "data" sheets
    itemFound = False
    For j = 1 To dataShtNumber 'loop through "data" worksheets

        Set rngToCopy = FindItems(dataShts(j), itemToFind, 1, columnsNumberToCopyAndPaste) ' get "data" sheet column 1 cells with "number" along with 'columnsNumberToCopyAndPaste-1' adjacents cells

        If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then ' if found any occurrence of the "number" ...
            rngToCopy.Copy itemsSht.Cells(1, 1).Offset(previousDataNumber + iRow) ' ... copy it and paste into "base" sheet
            iRow = iRow + rngToCopy.Count / columnsNumberToCopyAndPaste 'update "base" sheet row offset to paste subsequent cells, if any
            itemFound = True
        End If

    Next j
    If Not itemFound Then 'if NOT found any occurrence of the "number" ...
        itemsSht.Cells(1, 1).Offset(previousDataNumber + iRow).Value = itemToFind
        itemsSht.Cells(1, 2).Offset(previousDataNumber + iRow).Resize(1, columnsNumberToCopyAndPaste - 1).Value = "NOT FOUND"
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If

Next i

itemsSht.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub


Sub GetItems(itemsSht As Worksheet, items() As Variant, itemsNumber As Long, previousDataNumber As Long)

With itemsSht
    previousDataNumber = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    itemsNumber = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1 - previousDataNumber
    ReDim items(1 To itemsNumber) As Variant
    With .Cells(2 + previousDataNumber, 1).Resize(itemsNumber)
        If itemsNumber = 1 Then
            items(1) = .Value
        Else
            items = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Value)
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub


Function FindItems(sht As Worksheet, itemToFind As Variant, columnToSearchFor As Long, columnsToCopy As Long) As Range
Dim cell As Range, unionRng As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

With sht.Columns(columnToSearchFor)
    Set cell = .Find(What:=itemToFind, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = cell.Address
        Set unionRng = cell.Resize(, columnsToCopy)
        Do
            Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, cell.Resize(, columnsToCopy))

            Set cell = .FindNext(cell)
        Loop While Not cell Is Nothing And cell.Address <> firstAddress
        Set FindItems = unionRng
    End If
End With

End Function


Sub GetDataWorksheets(shts() As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, noShtName As String, nShts As Long)
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
    With sht
        If .Name <> noShtName Then
            nShts = nShts + 1
            ReDim Preserve shts(1 To nShts) As Worksheet
            Set shts(nShts) = sht
        End If
    End With
Next sht

End Sub
```

(*) Actually I added a `previousDataNumber` variable to track data already there at the time the routine runs

(**) in `columnsNumberToCopyAndPaste = 5` you set the number of columns to be handled

I split it into a "main" sub and some other "helper" subs or function in order to have clear and more maintainable/changeable code.

this habit has always helped me much more than I could ever expect at my beginnings, when I was used to code looong subs

Comment: Added "not found" case

Comment: It has an error in this line
items = WorksheetFunction.Transpose.(Value)

Comment: the line in  my code is "items = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Value)"  it's different from the one in your comment in that the dot is inside braces, instead of outside them as in your comment.   should you still get an error after correcting as above, specify what kind of error and which line throws it

Comment: Yes it gave me an error again ..
See the image please to see the error..
http://postimg.org/image/76kgpxt9l/

Comment: query itemsNumber value in the Immediate Window (type "?itemsNumber" and press return) or in the "locals" window

Comment: As usual I write the number in num column then I run the macro, Is my method wrong?

Comment: My code expects to find a "number" label in cell A1 of every sheet containing data to be searched in. And then there follow all numbers from cell A2 downwards

Comment: Could you solve my problem in Cornel code? I put it in the last comment

Comment: I saw from your last attached image that you label the number columns by "num". So I changed it in my GetDataWorksheets() function. Try it

Comment: It worked with me now,What I want here only if i did second search, it shouldn't do a search for previous search again. It should start searching from the row that we achieve
see the image please
postimg.org/image/ya9z2ws0b

Comment: It gives me an error again and it doesn't work. -> type mismatch
In getItem function
  items = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Value)
        .EntireRow.ClearContents

Comment: Also it gives me an error here :  Set FindItems = unionRng.Resize(, columnsToCopy) -> application defined error

Comment: You're mentioning two different rows. Which one throws the type mismatch error? Step through your code and once in the offending line query all variables that appear in that line

Comment: It doesn't help me to help you. tell me exactly which line first throws an error, what kind of error and the current value of all variables involved in that line. you may post screenshots of

Comment: Is it work with You?? ;( it gives me an error again. Can you upload the excel file if it is worked with you

Comment: the code is tested with an excel file with sheets just as those you posted shots of. if you upload your actual excel file I can give it a try

Comment: Finally it's worked.. How can I increase the number of columns? if i have a lot of information

Comment: updated code.  see line  `columnsNumberToCopyAndPaste = 5` to set the number of columns to be handled

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/ezRX/Book1.xlsx
sometimes it give me the results, and sometimes it give me errors :(

Comment: Check the excel file plz

Comment: can't download it. I'll not register to any site. try another uploader file

Comment: double click on book1.xlsx

Comment: Not in the possibility of doing it for some time. I think in some 10 hours I'll be able to do it. In the meanwhile you can step through the code and see what it does in order to catch the very conditions that throw an error. This is quite a common parte of the coding routine you'll always have to face. That way you'll be able to give me effective hints as to where put my attention.

Comment: it gaves me wrong detection. the value is available but it return not found.

Comment: it is still has an error in Redim itemes in GetItems function

Comment: I tested with the file you uploaded with no error. From now on if you want some help you have to always detail the error you meet: uploading the file (if changed), detailing the sequence of operation (first I put numbers .... in rows .. to .. of column "A" of "base" sheet and run the macro with no error. then I added numbers ... in rows .. to .. and run the macro and it throws error ... when hitting this code line) and attaching screenshot.

Comment: It's worked with me without any errors, but when there are replicated values in the same sheet it doesn't take them. for example,  here I searched for abc1, it should give me 3 values. It gives me only 2. 
see the image to understand what I mean
http://postimg.org/image/4gshy8im9/

Comment: @Freshteh Did you test it?

Comment: Yes I test it . It worked fine with this specific data but when i test it on another information it returned not found at all cells . I don't know why :(

Comment: If you upload new data I can take a look at it

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/336596/Searchresult.xlsm
plz check this one, I put a sample in it, when I search for the value it gives me not found. Plz can you find a solution to make it search for anything I write in the searching cells :( . It should search in all of the cells in each sheet in col A. If it finds a valuem it should return the related row. even it should support duplication in same sheet

Comment: my friend, you keep changing the header of the column where to search values in. at the beginning it was "number". then it became "num". now it's "name". It seems like you always need it to be as what in cell "A1" of "Sheet1". see updated code. Finally If you find my code is the actual solution to your original question, you may want to mark it as such and/or give reputation. thank you

Comment: You know why I keep changing? because it received me like this , for example one sheet written in first column name, second sheet: company name. So the header is changeable, I want it to search in each sheet regardless what is the header. Thank you very much for your help. I marked the answer but I don't know how to give reputation. If you can do it like what I want it will be meritorious

Comment: Please tell me if you will complete it for me or not. See the image plz. http://postimg.org/image/v2825keef/

Comment: poor software specs is software death... anyhow see updated code

Comment: Really thaaaanks a loooot... You are very loyal and ideal person.... You help me tell the end .... May God help you in all your life ... Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Now I fully understand the problem, I have edited my initial Script. Now it includes a FINDNEXT loop after the first FIND, this searches all the duplicate values on the sheet. This loops until FINDNEXT.cell.address  is the same as FIND.cell.address. To search only in column "A" I changed sheets(i).cells to sheets(i).Range("A:A") in the Find function

```
 Sub find_cells()
Dim find_cell As Range
Dim colection_items As Collection
Dim look_up_value As String

nb_rows = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'count the number of rows with data on sheet(1)

Set colection_items = New Collection
For j = 2 To nb_rows
  colection_items.Add Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value
Next j


counter_rows = 2 'the first row on sheet(2) where we start copying data from

For col = 1 To colection_items.Count

look_up_value = colection_items(col)
    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Select
        Set find_cell = Sheets(i).Range("A:A").Find(What:=look_up_value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

           If Not find_cell Is Nothing Then
              Dim cell_adrs As String
              cell_adrs = find_cell.Address  'record address of the first instance of the lookup value on the sheet (i)
               Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 1).Value = find_cell
               Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 2).Value = find_cell.Offset(0, 1) 'copies data from the cell to the left by one column
               Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 3).Value = find_cell.Offset(0, 2) 'copies data from the cell to the left by 2 columns
                'etc
               counter_rows = counter_rows + 1

                            Do
                                 Set find_cell = Sheets(i).Range("A:A").FindNext(find_cell)  'we lookup the next instance on sheet (i)
                                      If cell_adrs <> find_cell.Address Then    'if the next value found is different than the first value from sheet(i)
                                         Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 1).Value = find_cell
                                         Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 2).Value = find_cell.Offset(0, 1) 'copies data from the cell to the left by one column
                                         Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 3).Value = find_cell.Offset(0, 2) 'copies data from the cell to the left by 2 columns
                                          counter_rows = counter_rows + 1
                                          'etc
                                      End If
                                Loop Until cell_adrs = find_cell.Address 'when all the values have been found and find_cell goes back to the first value
                            cell_adrs = Empty
            End If

    Next i
Next col
Sheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it will work even if I have 20 sheets or more?

Comment: And How can I create a button to do my job here? I want to click on it

Comment: I checked it, it works fine. But It doesn't give me the values related in columns D, E and F. Why ?

Comment: Oh Ok, I changed the offset value and it is Ok now. but plz help me in adding button to do all of these

Comment: You can add any shape or button, right click on it and click on Assign Macro, select the macro "find_cells". Clicking the button should run the script on the whole workbook. Please let me know if you meant something else with your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, If I faced any questions I'll tell you

Comment: How can I add this thing, if the value is not found It should appear in the whole cells not found

Comment: Are you referring to "If Not find_cell Is Nothing Then"?

Comment: Yes, I mean if it find the value it will copy it. But if it doesn't find it , I want it to return "Not found" 
I added this thing in the code
Is it right?
Before End IF

Else
Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 2).Value ="Not found"
Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 3).Value ="Not found"
End If

Comment: it should be:       Else                                                                                                      Sheets(1).Cells(counter_rows, 2).Value ="Not found"                   counter_rows = counter_rows + 1      End If

Comment: Exuse me, your code dosn't give me the duplicalted data in the same sheet .. Why ? What should I add to fix this problem ?

Comment: Also, i want it to search in column A only in each sheet.. it searched for me in every cell .. What should i do??

Comment: The previous problem is solved, now it can put the duplicated in the same sheet also.
Now I have another problem. See the upload image please, to understand what I mean.
http://postimg.org/image/wplr2st3t/
Even if I write 5 for example, and there is abc5, abc15, it takes the cells that contain 5 all.
But it should search for (5) separate and if it doesn’t find it should return not found. Please fix this problem.

Comment: It should search for a specific value for example RTNA102345
And if there exactly same value in sheets, it should return it. If it is not found, it should return not found. But if it found for example RTNA10234 
It shouldn't return it because it is different than our specific value searching

Comment: change "LookAt:=xlPart" with "LookAt:=xlWhole" in   "Set find_cell = Sheets(i).Range("A:A").Find(What:=look_up_value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)"

Comment: You mean I have to replace "Set find_cell = Sheets(i).Range("A:A").FindNext(find_cell)" by what you wrote, right?

Comment: Because there are 2 Set find cell, you mean the first one or the second?

Comment: Another question, why if I did a search for first time, for many numbers and i miss to put 2 numbers for example, it repeats the search again and it put the same data again. I want you to put something that if did a search for one time It shouldn't repeat it. See the image to understand what I mean.
http://postimg.org/image/ya9z2ws0b/

Comment: Please change counter_rows = 2 to -> counter_rows  = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    This adds new rows below the ones already entered and please put the items that you want to look for on say column 10 of sheet(1) and change      colection_items.Add Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value to     colection_items.Add Sheets(1).Cells(j, 10).Value

Comment: It doesn't give me anything,every thing is correct in the code 
but What I want here only if i did second search, it shouldn't do a search for previous search again. It should start searching from the row that we reached

Comment: I forgot about changhing nb_rows = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row to ->nb_rows = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row. This counts the number of new items to lookup in column 10. The items that you lookup should be in a different place from the area that you paste the values

Comment: If you check my first code, you will understand what I mean. Try it please, It doesn't repeat the search for all numbers in second searching. Everything in your code is Ok. But I want a solution for not repeating searching for the previous values

Comment: You should have the lookup values in a different area, after you run the search, delete the old values and add new ones

Comment: What If I want to not delete the old value?
I want if i did a new search, it should search for a specific value only. Is it impossible to do that?